# Get value check box

Tags: php

`a_moip` and `a_google_analy` are integers in the database as the other strings

```
<?
@$c_google = $_POST['c_google_analystics'];
@$c_moip = $_POST['c_moip'];

$code = $_POST['google_analystic'];
$token = $_POST['moip_token'];
$key = $_POST['moip_key'];

if(isset($c_google) or isset($c_moip)) {

    if(!isset($c_google)) {
        $c_google == 0;
        $code == NULL;
    }
    else {
        $c_google == 1;
    }

    if(!isset($c_moip)) {
        $c_moip == 0;
        $key == NULL;
        $token == NULL;
    }
    else {
        $c_moip == 1;
    }

    $q = new Query;
    $q
            ->update('config')
            ->set(
                    array(
                        'a_google_analy' => $c_google,
                        'a_moip' => $c_moip,
                        'google_analy' => $code,
                        'moip_token' => $token,
                        'moip_key' => $key
                    )
            )
            ->where_equal_to(
                    array(
                        'id' => 1 // bug fix
                    )
            )
            ->run();
}
else {

    $q = new Query;
    $q
            ->update('config')
            ->set(
                    array(
                        'a_google_analy' => 0,
                        'a_moip' => 0,
                        'google_analy' => NULL,
                        'moip_token' => NULL,
                        'moip_key' => NULL
                    )
            )
            ->where_equal_to(
                    array(
                        'id' => 1 // bug fix
                    )
            )
            ->run();
}
?>
```

I made a print in the array, the variable is not being treated, always appears when it is checked 'on'.

Comment: is it possible to show your html code  ?

Comment: When you are fresh enough, please advise what is the actual question to resolve?

Comment: Yeah. You really need to relax and than ask for a help. Right now it is completely not clear what are you talking about. At least, show HTML code of checkbox you have a problem with. But as a guess - specify value for that input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used double equal sign `==` for asigning value to variables like

```
$c_google == 0;
$code == NULL;
```

use single `=` please correct all of them

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox must have a value. Suppose right now you have something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name" />
```

value is not specified but browser must to send some value to server on submit. Default is `on` and that is why you are getting `on` when checked. When checkbox is not checked - its value is not sent at all.

If you want to get some specific value in `$_POST` when checkbox is checked, just add `value="some_val"` to your checkbox tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name" value="some_value" />
```

Comment: I ran into this not long ago and it had me scratching my head. Why an off value isn't sent by default is beyond me.

Comment: You could extend this by adding `<input type="hidden" name="some_name" value="off">` before the checkbox. If the checkbox value is actually sent it should override the hidden input. If it isn't, the hidden input will be sent.